# using trigger on a collection of objects

Tags: javascript, jquery

somewhat new to jquery but i love it so much I have been plowing through development for the last few weeks straight on a proof of concept.

I am trying to implement a trigger on multiple objects but no matter what i do it only fires on the first object in the collection. I know that triggerHandler has this limitation but trigger should now.  I thought that for trigger this would work!  please help!

This is what I currently have:

a bunch of input boxes with the same class (e.g.

```
input type="checkbox" id="checkX" class="allchecks" value="show" />`
```

)

Then a button that i want to trigger a click on all of them and run the click handler on each

```
<input type="button" value="select all" value="click me" id="button1" />
```

Then...

```
$j('#button1').click(function(){
  $j('.allchecks').each(function(){
       if(!$j(this).is(':checked')){   
           $j(this).trigger('click');
       }
  }); // end each
}); // end click
```

seems no matter what i do only the first object has it's bound click event fired.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

**update**: Out of frustration i wrote the same code except without using the each loop I manually triggered each one separately and it fails in the same way -- it only triggers the event on the first object and stops.

**update**: Here is an example of the click event bound to the inputs:

```
$j('#checkx').click(function(){ /* do something */ }); //end click
```

**update**: oops copy /paste error, fixed it. But it doesn't detract from the question.

Comment: Maybe the event handler is throwing an error, preventing the execution of the other handlers. Please create a http://jsfiddle.net/ demo.

Comment: I don't understand how anyone can write javascript code and not use the error console or debug console to see script errors.  Learn how to do that right away.  It would show you this error and will save you hours of time in the future.

Comment: There are no errors.  I use firebug in firefox, get it working there  then check other browsers.  I don't understand how you...nevermind, not worth it.

Answer (score 1):

Your code's missing a `)`:

```
if(!$j(this).is(':checked'){
```

See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/orig/GP3gJ/)

PS. You don't need the `.each`:

```
$j('#button1').click(function(){
  $j('.allchecks:not(:checked)').trigger('click');
}); // end click
```

See [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/orig/GP3gJ/1/)

**EDIT** You're using the same id on multiple elements, that's a no-no. It doesn't work and now you've seen why and you'll never do it again ;-)

```
$j('.allchecks').click(function(){ /* do something */ });
```

Comment: yes, ok, my bad on the syntax error...copy / paste edit error here.  I fixed that. Turns out, it does work in jsfiddle but not here! I don't know why as I'm not getting any errors.  I updated the [js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GP3gJ/5/) to make it more like what i'm actually doing to prove it to myself.

Comment: Not using the same ID -- see the updated fiddle from earlier. The X was an example.  But GOOD NEWS i found the cause. When you click on a checkbox the "checked" happens first and then the callback.  But when you trigger the click the event callback happens first and then the "checked". Here is what i had to do to call the trigger:  set the mark, let it fire, set it again!  toggle() wasn't a good example because i wasn't technically doing a toggle,so you couldn't detect this easily. The code for the trigger call 
`$j('.histtoggles').prop('checked',true).trigger('click').prop('checked',true);`

Comment: Great, but you can also bind on `change` and then do `$j('.histtoggles').prop('checked',true).trigger('change')`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need trigger click event to check the check box, just use the `prop` method to set the `checked` to  true. See the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/JUqWP/).

```
$('#button1').click(function(){
    $('.allchecks').prop('checked', true);
});
```